# undefined method `_path' when using params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails and currently I'm building a game app. My game contains multiple levels. I want the url of the game to contain the number of each level. For example:

```
http://localhost:3000/game1/play/1
http://localhost:3000/game1/play/2
```

In order to achieve this, I understand that I need to use params, here's my code:

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :game1

  get "/game1" => "game1#index"
  get "/game1/play/:level" => "game1#play"
  get "/game1/instruction" => "game1#instruction"


  get "/pages/*page" => "pages#show"
  get "/pages/about" => "pages#about"

  root "pages#show", page: "home"

end
```

controller:

```
class Game1Controller < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def play

        @game1 = Game1lv.find(params[:level])

        @userid = current_user.id
        @usergame1lv = User.where(id: @userid).limit(1).pluck(:game1lv) 
        if @usergame1lv == [nil]
            @usergame1lv = 1
        end

        @game1l = Game1lv.where(:level => @usergame1lv).limit(1).pluck(:imagelink)
        @game1a = Game1lv.where(:level => @usergame1lv).limit(1).pluck(:answer)
        @game1link = @game1l[0].to_s
        @game1answer = @game1a[0].to_s

        @game1answer_user = params["answer"]

        if @game1answer_user == @game1answer
            redirect_to game1_play_path(@game1), :flash => { :success => "You are right!" }
        else
            #flash.now[:alert] = 'You are wrong! Lets try again!'
        end

    end

    def instruction
    end

end
```

view:

```
<body><center>

    <br><b>Answer: </b><br><br>

    <%= form_tag game1_play_path(@game1), :method => :get, :id => "text_form" do %>

        <%= text_field_tag "answer", "" ,class: 'textbox_game' %>
        <br><br>
        <%= submit_tag("Submit", :class => "button_game") %>

    <% end %>


</center></body>
```

Now when I go to the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/game1/play/1
```

Rails show the error:

```
undefined method `game1_play_path' for #<#<Class:0x943de50>:0x9447720>
```

Rails indicate that the error is at this line in the view file:

```
<%= form_tag game1_play_path(@game1), :method => :get, :id => "text_form" do %>
```

Please show me what I'm doing wrong and why that method is undefined. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this `get "/game1/play/:level" => "game1#play", as: 'game1_play'`

Comment: thank you so much pavan!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Pavan, you can force the path to be defined your way using `as: :path_name`.

Before that, I would have a look at my routes to make sure everything is defined to begin with and that you don't have unnecessary routes.

If you don't need to communicate with your server in a RESTful way, then perhaps it's a bad idea to use `resources` since this will lead to internal errors.

You can check your routes using `rake routes` or while in development you can go to `localhost:port/rails/info/routes`.

At first glance, I would suspect that your path is actually `play_game1_path(@game1)`, with the action first.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `resources :game1` which gives you a seven methods: index, new, create, show, edit, update, destroy. You should only specify the ones you want to use like

```
resources :game1, only: [:index]
```

You can also make things more organized with nested routes by

```
resources :game1, only: [:index] do
  get "instruction"
end

resources :pages, only: [:show] do
  get "about"
end
```

With this setup, you will need a PagesController. The default param for show routes is `:id`

Resource: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: First, no you shouldn't use `resources` like you are suggesting. Based off his controllers, he shouldn't use `resource(s)` at all. Second, using `resources` for static pages is insanely wrong. For static pages, you need to either define everything individually or use Thoughtbot's High Voltage gem. Third, you didn't contribute anything really to this problem.

Comment: He could definitely go without using resources and specify each route. I feel like it is always better to try to make your routes be RESTful if possible. Also, the play action of his Game1Controller is dynamic.

Comment: High Voltage creates a `PagesController` and tons more neat stuff. It's not going to remove the other controllers or make them static. And you're 100% right about making things Restful. I mean ffs why Game1? It could of easily been `resources :games` and have a nested `resources :levels` and just use `GamesController#show` instead of `play`. But one battle at a time I guess.